# Rinsim: add another PDPObject other than Parcel, Depot or Vehicle

Tags: java, rinsim

We want to add a ConnectionAgent that monitors a certain connection to the `PDPRoadModel` in order to support reservations. However, these ConnectionAgents have `CommDevice`s, which require a position in order to be useful, which means the devices have to be `PDPObject`s.

If we implement them as a `Vehicle`, they can cause collisions with the existing vehicles and we still want to simulate collisions, so this is impossible. If we implement them as `Parcel`s, they show up on the grid, which covers up the actual `Parcel`s, which is something we're trying to avoid.

As the `PDPType` object is protected, we can't implement a new `PDPType`, meaning that we currently have no way to implement our ConnectionAgent properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work around the restrictions of the `PDPRoadModel` by not adding the `ConnectionAgent` to the models as a physical entity but just as a virtual communication entity that has a certain position. For example, the agent could be implemented similar to this:

```
public class ConnectionAgent implements CommUser {
  final Point position;

  public ConnectionAgent(Connection<LengthData> c) {
    position = Point.centroid(asList(c.from(), c.to()));
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<Point> getPosition() {
    return Optional.of(position);
  }

  @Override
  public void setCommDevice(CommDeviceBuilder builder) {}
}
```

If you want to have an agent for each connection, you could just loop over the connections in the graph, and then create and add the `ConnectionAgent` to the simulator.